# Building an STL application in Borland C++ Builder 5.0

Tags: stl, c++builder, c++builder-5

I am new to Borland C++ builder 5.0.I have used small STL application which is compiled successfully in one machine(Window 2003 Server SP2), but not in another machine (Windows XP machine SP3). I have placed an code snippet and error message

```
Error E2285 Could not find a match for 'distance<>(const AnsiString *,const AnsiString *,i
nt)
```

I have opened Borland C++ Form and added the below code in Form Create

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using std::distance;

static const AnsiString Text_FieldsInTypen[]=
{
  "code_segment_national_2"
};

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
   vector<AnsiString> aVec;
   aVec.push_back("Test");

   const AnsiString*  Iter;
   int Index = 0;
   distance(Text_FieldsInTypen, Iter, Index);

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi there. Please format your code next time :) Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 2):

The distance algorithm takes two iterators:

```
template<class InputIterator>
   typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
      distance(
         InputIterator _First, 
         InputIterator _Last
            );
```

Not three unrelated arguments.

`Iter` is also used uninitialized in your code.

Comment: I have checked in "iterator.h" file present in the location "C:\Progtam Files\Borland\CBuilder 5\include\rw\iterator.h   which has three parameters as shown below                                                               template <class ForwardIterator, class Distance>
  inline void distance (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Distance& n) 
  {    .....  } .

Comment: Thanks Alex , I will align the code next time.  I have been struggling in this error message for a long time. The same code works fine in Windows Server 2003 .  Please do the needfull .

Comment: I have changed the AnsiString to char* then it compiles for distance() with three arguments. Please let me know why it is not able to identify the distance() for AnsiString

Comment: Because the input iterators have to be the same type, but you are passing a char[] as the first iterator. For that matter, your code will not work anyway, even if it compiles, because the two iterators need to belong to the same container.  What are you trying to accomplish by passing a char[] as the first iterator and an (uninitialized) Vector iterator as the second iterator?